# How do I define LocalLeader as <Space>?

Tags: vimrc, leader

I need to define `LocalLeader` for various plugins and I would like to set it to `<Space>`. If I add this to my `vimrc` file

```
let maplocalleader = "<Space>"
```

typing space in normal mode just moves the cursor by one position (i.e. my command had no effect). Setting the `LocalLeader` to

```
let maplocalleader = "\\"
```

allows mappings to work properly when prefixed by `\`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use this:

```
let maplocalleader="\<space>"
```

Note that the mapping is the same for the reguler leader `let mapleader="\<Space>"`

Comment: Thanks! I never thought I would need to escape that, it kind of defeats the point of having the `<space>` specifier.

Comment: @PaulIrofti See [`:h expr-quote`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-quote) actually `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` are VIM string variables thus it is not that surprising to escape the special keys. Also you should be able to use `let maplocalleader = " "`

Comment: The first thing I did was to try `maplocalleader = " "`, but it did not work in my case. Thanks for the help reference!

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
let mapleader = " "
let maplocalleader = " "
```